# Simple PHP Google Places API request

Tags: php, api

So if I put this in my browser URL:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=45.508867,-73.554242&radius=500&sensor=false&key=mykey
```

It works. But if I try the exact same call in PHP I get ACCESS DENIED:

```
<?php
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "location=45.508867,-73.554242&radius=500&sensor=false&key=mykey");
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  echo $result;
?>
```

I tried many different options and minor changes but nothing works and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this for testing purposes, make sure SSL verification is not enabled, as it will prevent it may prevent the request form being executed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing this curl setting:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$latitude = 27.7172;
$longitude = 85.3240;
$radius = 50000;
$name = "kupondole";    
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?name=".urlencode($name)."&location=".$latitude.",".$longitude."&radius=".$radius."&key=MY_KEY";
            $ch = curl_init();
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch);
```

Works perfectly fine.